# how can i quit when I use curl_easy_perform?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I want to quit `curl_easy_perform` everywhere,not only download data or timeout
I can quit when writefunc return a nonzero ,can quit when timeout.

But when i try to connect to a server, something happened, i should quit immediately, but `curl_easy_perform` still wait timeout. How can i do when this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Not use curl_easy_perform .
use curl_multi_perform and select  instead of curl_easy_perform